# ending input loop when input file is routed through stdin at end of file

Tags: c++, unix

I have to end a loop receiving strings once the last string has been taken. The input is from a file by redirected to stdin. I have to do this automatically and not by input of any keys in run-time. If any external input is the only solution then what should be the corresponding code in c++?

Comment: thanks! i didn't get this in suggestions! the one i got didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (! stream.eof()) {
    // read from stream
}
```

Comment: wont't this read one extra bit **after** the eof

Comment: this is also assuming
    fstream stream;
    stream.open('foo.txt');